# Parallel Translation is Path Independent iff Manifold is Flat

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

**Problem.** Let $M$ be a smooth Riemannian manifold and $\nabla$ be the Levi-Civita connection. Then the following are equivalent

1. $R(X,Y)Z=\nabla_X\nabla_YZ-\nabla_Y\nabla_XZ-\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z\equiv 0$
2. For all $p,q\in M$, parallel translation along a curve segment from $p$ to $q$ is independent of the curve.

**My attempt.** I've tried for several hours now, but I'm out of ideas. Initially, I tried analyzing the differential equations which characterize  a vector field along a curve being parallel, but I couldn't get anything out of it.

For the implication (2)$\implies$(1), it would be enough to show $R(\partial_i,\partial_j)\partial_k\equiv0$. Considering curves through some $p\in M$ which have the form $t\mapsto te_i$ in some chart around $p$ seemed promising but didn't get me far.

In particular I'm also not sure how the fact that $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita conncetion comes into play. I know that compatibility of $\nabla$ with the metric is equivalent to the parallel translation being an isometry. Can we use that?

I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: $ 1 \implies 2 $ is not true unless you restrict the allowed curves - consider a Mobius strip.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Could you please elaborate on that a bit? Why does the Mobius strip satisfy (1) but not (2)?

Comment: You can construct a Mobius strip from a flat sheet of paper, so it is flat. (More rigorously, take $\mathbb R \times [0,1]$ and identify $(x,0)$ with $(-x,1)$ - since we just glued a flat surface it's still flat.) If you draw a closed curve that makes a single loop of the surface and parallel transport a vector around, it will flip vertically. This is "global holonomy" - curvature only tells us about *local* holonomy.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @AnthonyCarapetis. Using a similar argument, the Klein bottle and projective plane also possess flat metrics with parallel transport *not* independent of the curve, right?

Comment: that's correct.

Comment: with $[\partial_i,\partial_j] = 0$ : $ \ \ \ R(\partial_i,\partial_j)Z = \nabla_{\partial_i} \nabla_{\partial_j}  Z - \nabla_{\partial_j} \nabla_{\partial_i}  Z $  which is clearly measuring how much an (infinitesimal) step in the direction $\partial_i$ followed by a step in the direction $\partial_j$ is different from a step in the direction $\partial_j$ followed by a step in the direction $\partial_i$

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Is 1 $\Rightarrow$ 2 true if I only consider homotopic curves?

Answer (score 4):

For the path independence part:

Recall that $\nabla$ is flat iff $R^{a}_{bcd}=0$ everywhere on $M$. If the parallel transport of vectors along a path on $M$ relative to $\nabla$ is indeed path independent then $\nabla$ is flat.

Conversely, if $\nabla$ is flat then, at least locally, parallel transport of vectors on $M$ relative to $\nabla$ is path independent.

To prove this, firstly assume that parallel transport of vectors on $M$ **is** path independent. Let $p$ be any point in $M$ and let $\boldsymbol{\zeta^{a}}$ be any vector at $p$. Extend $\boldsymbol{\zeta^{a}}$ to a smooth vector field $\boldsymbol{\pi^{a}}$ by parallel transporting $\boldsymbol{\zeta^{a}}$ to through *any* curve to all points of $M$. The resulting field is constant in the sense that $\nabla_{a}\pi^{b}=0$ everywhere; this is equivalent to saying that **all** directional derivatives vanish everywhere.

Hence,
\begin{align}
R^{a}_{bcd}\pi^{b}&= -2 \nabla_{[c} \nabla_{d]}\pi^{b} \\
                    &=0
\end{align}
everywhere, and in particular, at $p$. Since the choice of $\zeta$ was arbitrary, $R^{a}_{bcd}=0$.

Now for the converse argument. Assume that $R^{a}_{bcd}=0$ on $M$. In order we show that, at least locally, parallel transport is path-independent it will be sufficient to show that at any given $\zeta^{a}$ at arbitrary $p$, we can extend $\zeta^{a}$ to any smooth $\boldsymbol{\pi^{a}}$ on some open set $O$ containing $p$ that is constant. That is to say, 
$$\nabla_{a}\pi^{b}=0$$
everywhere on $O$.

this last part is tricky insofar as one needs to find local coordinates that satisfies a set of PDEs such that

\begin{align}
\nabla_{a}\pi^{b}&=0\\
\pi^{a}_{|p}&=\zeta^{a}
\end{align}
the set of PDEs that fall out of computation will be satisfied iff (as it turns out through copious lines of algebra) $R^{a}_{bcd}=0$ expressed in local coordinates.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am a bit confused. What exactly do you mean by $R^{a}_{bcd}$?

Comment: Ah! By $R^{a}_{bcd}$ I mean the Riemann curvature tensor. it expresses the curvature of Riemannian manifolds, by assigning a tensor to every point on the manifold $M$ and assesses to what extent the manifold is not isometric to Euclidean space. so, for our purpose, $R^{a}_{bcd}=0$ means that the manifold **is** isometric to $\mathbb{E}^{n}$ and hence, flat. Check http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannTensor.html

Comment: @iwriteonbananas $R^a_{bcd}$ is the application $X,Y,Z \to R(X,Y)Z$ expressed in local coordinates https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor#Coordinate_expression and $R^\rho_{ijk} = 0$ is exactly what you wrote above : $dx^\rho R(\partial_i,\partial_j)\partial_k = 0$

Answer (score 1):

For the direction: $2) \Rightarrow 1)$ use [this formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1378538/computation-in-wikipedias-article-riemann-curvature-tensor?rq=1), which connects the curvature tensor to parallel transport along small closed loops.

$1) \Rightarrow 2):$ (which as pointed by Anthony Carapetis hols only locally):

Any flat mnaifold is locally isometric to Euclidean space, so you can transfer the parallel transport to $(\mathbb{R}^n,e)$, do it there, and then project back to your manifold. Since parallelt transport in $(\mathbb{R}^n,e)$ is trivially path independent, we finished.

Comment: $1) \implies 2)$ is always true when the closed curve is restricted to lie in a single diffeomorphism $A \subseteq  \mathcal{M} \to B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$